# Android operating with activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have  back `Button` in my `Activity` which starts dashboard `Activity`. Everytime user tries to go back to dashboard - it is recreated. But when user tries to navigate through usual back button he sees a lot of same screens. Do I have to check if an `Activity` already started and if yes - show it instead of creating the same activity one more time?

Comment: you can use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` of your child's activities definitions.

Answer (score 0):

-->You can keep a global **flag** which will have a value say **0 initially**.
-->Now,when the dashboard activity is created,set the **flag value to 1**.
-->Now,when you press your back button,just check **the value of flag**,
---->if **flag==1**,Just finish the activity and don't create dashboard activity.It will safely land back to your dashboard activity.
---->And if the **flag==0**,then create a new dashboard activity.